# How to process faster on .gz files in spark scala?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks, azure-databricks

I am reading .gz file as

```
val df = spark.read..format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .load("filepath.gz")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

When when I am doing processing, it takes whole lot of time. 
How it can be minimize?

Comment: From wich type of storage do you read these data ? 

Are there stored in HDFS ?

Comment: @airliquide , No,its not HDFS. Its a single file stored on cloud.

Comment: Probably your point of slow down ! Try to get a more faster storage (closer to you processing point). most of the time of slow down is linked to you cloud data access.

Answer (score 3):

.gzip is not a good format for use with Spark as that compression codec is not splittable.   So, Spark has to process it on a single node and it will always be slow.

If possible, I would recommend changing your compression codec to something else that is splittable, or pre-processing your files outside of Spark first, to convert to another format, before trying to process them with Spark.  For example, you could write a small shell script that would uncompress and convert your files before attempting to read them with Spark.

See this for more info on the compression formats: http://comphadoop.weebly.com/

By the way, CSV is also not a great format on Spark either.  CSV is also not necessarily splittable if your records have embedded newlines in them.  In which case you're still processing on a single node.

I would recommend using Parquet with Snappy compression for the best all around performance.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments for clarification ... you should look to faster storage (HDSF,S3,Alluxio ... ) to get better performances.

You spend most of you time to access the data file in you cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use a splittable gzip codec. See https://github.com/nielsbasjes/splittablegzip/issues/2

Answer (score -1):

If your data being stored in a single csv file it processed by single worker. To benefit from massive parallel processing you should split your data into multiple files or use splittable file format (like ORC or Parquet).

To split single file into multiple files you could use `repartition` like this:

```
df.repartition(100).write.orc(location)
```

Comment: I need to read and process not write. Can you suggest something on reading and processing side?

Comment: @RaviAnandVicky I didn't tried it by myself, but you could try to use alternative gzip codec with support for reading gzip in parallel, like [this](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/splittablegzip/blob/master/README-Spark.md)

Comment: @shuvaloc , This still not solved the processing time.

Answer (score -1):

So. Usually when speaking about performance there are few ways for improvement:

1. Get more or more powerful hardware
2. Use cloud to get more powerful
   hardware
3. Grant more resources to your job.
4. Optimize your code.

In your case you hardly can optimize anything in code - only one file only one operation. So 4 is no-go.

Increasing number of cores can hardly do any better due to same reasons. Though you could try it. (3) Same goes with memory.

So basically only first two options are left.